# how to hide image by its icon-value

Tags: javascript, html, css

hi everyone i cant find the solution for my question on google. i just want to hide the images using there icon-value
like in the below example i just want to hide the image which have icon-value="1" in the div which have .box class

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="icon"><img src="xyz/smiley.png" icon-value="1" icon-index="0"></div>
  <div class="icon"><img src="xyz/1.png" icon-value="2" icon-index="1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use an attribute selector.

```
.box img[icon-value="1"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Isn't a quote needed for this to work? `.box img[icon-value="1"] {display: none;
}`

Comment: Apparently you're right. I'm used to jQuery, which is less strict than CSS.

Answer (score 2):

**CSS solution:**

```
.box img[icon-value="1"] {
    display: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MPnmF/1/)

*PS: Notice the value in quotes. I don't think CSS attribute selectors will work if the value is not specified in quotes*

**jQuery solution:**

```
$(".box img[icon-value=1]").css("display", "none");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/vW56x/)

Answer (score 2):

using css try following

```
.box .icon img[icon-value="1"] {
        display: none;
    }
```

or if you are using jquery you can try this also

```
$(".box img[icon-value=1]").hide();
```